# Right alignment of column in table column

Tags: tables, columns

I have a table defined as follows where the first column is right-justified:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{>{\hfill}p{3.50cm}p{5.50cm}p{5.50cm}}
\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
\textbf{Column 1} & \textbf{Column 2} & \textbf{Column 3} \\ [0.5ex]
\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
1 & text & text \\
2 & text & text \\
\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
\end{tabular}
\caption{thisTable.}
\label{tab:thisTable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

However, the column heading of the first column is also right-justified.

Can I change the column heading to be left-justified but leave the values contents of the data part of the column right-aligned?

Comment: `\hfill` does not right justify a paragraph, it just distorts the first line. use `\raggedright` or `\raggedleft` or in the final column use `\raggedright\arraybackslash`

Comment: for the heading use `\multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries column 1}` {or `l`)

Comment: Sorry, I'm not good with LaTex tables. How precisely do I implement what you are suggesting?

Comment: Your code was incomplete and contained a couple of errors. I've taken the liberty of fixing it up so that it's compilable.

Comment: Thanks Mico. I see your changes but how can I get the title of the first column to left-align?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> Can I change the column heading to be left-justified but leave the values contents of the data part of the column right-aligned?

Yes. Just place the cell's contents in a `\multicolumn{1}{l}{...}` "wrapper".

Incidentally, instead of using the somewhat kludgy `\hline\noalign{\smallskip}` directives, I suggest you load the `booktabs` package and use its macros `\toprule`, `\midrule`, and `\botttomrule` to get well-spaced horizontal lines.

And, instead of the `>{\hfill}p{3.50cm}` specification of the left-most column, I suggest you load the `array` and `ragged2e` packages and define a raggedleft (flushright) column type that takes a width parameter, as is done in the example below.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in,a4paper]{geometry}  % choose margins appropriately
\usepackage{array,booktabs,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\RaggedLeft\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ R{3.50cm} p{5.50cm} p{5.50cm} }
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Column 1}} & \textbf{Column 2} & \textbf{Column 3} \\ 
\midrule
1 & text & text \\
2 & text & text \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{thisTable.}
\label{tab:thisTable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum* to address the OP's follow-up question: If the cell in question has a lot of text that needs to span several lines, you can still use `\multicolumn`, but not with the `l` column type specifier. E.g., you might type

```
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
```

in the preamble and then write

```
\multicolumn{1}{L{3.50cm}}{An incredibly long header that occupies several lines.}
```

instead of the earlier

```
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Column 1}}
```

In short, `\multicolumn` is a very powerful and flexible tool.

Comment: Thanks Mico. I'm just trying to get the relevant .sty files now.

Comment: Just one issue that has arisen: if the text of the first column heading is quite long, I notice that it doesn't wrap. Can this be done?

Comment: @MrMorgan If you want multiline then you don't want `\multicolumn` just `\raggedright Column1` will work (or `\RaggedRight` )

Comment: @MrMorgan - I've provided an addendum to address your follow-up question.

Comment: Works great. But how to ensure a vertical alignment of the text in the cells above? My text is on the bottom as other cells grow in height.

Comment: @delrocco - I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "vertical alignment of the text in the cells above? Which cells? Above what? May I suggest you pose a *new question*, in which you state (a) what you've been doing so far, ideally with compilable LaTeX code, and (b) what the problem is? Thanks.

Comment: @Mico Sure, sorry about that, it wasn't very clear. I used that table (that you posted above). And some of the cells I have an image in. Thus the cells with text are now all vertically aligned to the bottom of the cells, not vertically in the middle of each cell. I thought there might be an easy one-liner to account for that, but I understand if it requires a totally new question. Thx

Comment: @delrocco - I would like to encourage you to post a new query, in which you would provide an example of your formatting objectives and of what you've tried so far. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

A variation on @Mico's solution, that uses the `makecell` package: it's designed to have a common formatting for columnheads in one command (`\thead`), thus saving some typing and, most importantly in my opinion, it's better semantically. I also allowed myself to put the caption on top, as is the typographical norm for tables and added the `caption` package so as to ensure a correct vertical spacing between caption and table.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, caption}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadalign{lc}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{thisTable.}
\label{tab:thisTable}
\begin{tabular}{>{\RaggedLeft}p{3.50cm}p{5.50cm}p{5.50cm}}
\toprule
\thead{Column 1} & \thead{Column 2} & \thead{Column 3} \\
\midrule
1 & text & text \\[0.5ex]
2 & text & text \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]