# Autofit a table to the column width

Tags: tables, two-column

I am creating a two-column document using latex. I use the option `\columnwidth` to autofit a table to the column width, as shown in the following figure. The second column `Value` is too wide. How do I set equal width for two columns?

---

[image]

---

Here is my source code.

```
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{Simulation parameters}
    \begin{tabular}{l|l}
        \hline
        Key                 & Value    \\
        \hline
        simulation duration & 12 hours \\
        update interval     & 1s       \\
        time-to-live        & 12 hours \\
        buffer size         & infinite \\
        message interval    & 20s      \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{Simulation parameters}
    \begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{l|l}
        \hline
        Key                 & Value    \\
        \hline
        simulation duration & 12 hours \\
        update interval     & 1s       \\
        time-to-live        & 12 hours \\
        buffer size         & infinite \\
        message interval    & 20s      \\
        \hline
    \end{tabularx}
    \label{table: simulation parameters}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Do you want to fix the length of both columns to the same? You can use `p{'width'}` instead of `l` as the second `tabular` parameter to do this. If not, could you describe what you mean with "the second column is to wide"? I'm not exactly sure what's the problem in your first table.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**EDIT**

@Mico pointed out a much better solution to this problem, as `tabularx` already comes with the column type `X`, which automatically does what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \caption{Simulation parameters}
    \begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{X|X}
        \hline
        Key                 & Value    \\
        \hline
        simulation duration & 12 hours \\
        update interval     & 1s       \\
        time-to-live        & 12 hours \\
        buffer size         & infinite \\
        message interval    & 20s      \\
        \hline
    \end{tabularx}
    \label{table: simulation parameters}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

---

As you already know the total width of your table, you can define the width of the columns as a fraction of `\columnwidth`

```
\documentclass{article}

\newlength\mylength
\setlength\mylength{\dimexpr.5\columnwidth-2\tabcolsep-0.5\arrayrulewidth\relax}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    %% \centering % not needed
    \caption{Simulation parameters}
    \begin{tabular}{p{\mylength}|p{\mylength}}
        \hline
        Key                 & Value    \\
        \hline
        simulation duration & 12 hours \\
        update interval     & 1s       \\
        time-to-live        & 12 hours \\
        buffer size         & infinite \\
        message interval    & 20s      \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \label{table: simulation parameters}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Since you're using a `tabularx` environment, you should write `\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{X|X}`. (Note that with your method, the total width is `\columnwidth+4\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth`.) Separately, if the width is set to `\columnwidth`, the instruction `\centering` may be omitted.

Comment: @Mico Thanks for the suggestion, I edited my answer.

Comment: +1. I've taken the liberty of editing the code of your second example a bit, e.g., by performing the calculation of the `p` columns in the preamble and by using a `tabular` environment instead of a `tabularx` environment. (The facilities of the `tabularx` environment aren't utilized in the second example.)

Comment: What is the meaning of `p` in `p{\mylength}`?

Comment: @Viesturs p is a column with specific width.

Comment: What if I want to define the width of a column and also tell that the alignment be `l`,  `c` or `r`?

Comment: @Viesturs Then you google and find answer like https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/199747/36296