# How can I align text right in a table that has a list?

Tags: align

This is what I have now

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[margin=1.0in]{geometry}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault} 

\setlist{nolistsep,leftmargin=0.25in}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}p{1in} @{}p{5.3in}}

    \textbf{Education} &
        \textbf{University of Waterloo} \hfill Waterloo, Canada \vspace{0.015in} \\ &
        Bachelor of Science \hfill May 2023 \vspace{0.015in}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Relevant Coursework: Computer Organization
        \end{itemize} \\ 
        
    \textbf{Awards} &
        \textbf{Google} - Google Generation Scholarship\hfill{2022}\\&

\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

And this is what I'd like to have:
[image]

Namely, I am referring to how the second image has the labels on the left hand side aligned to the right so there is uniform spacing between the labels and content to the right of the labels. In this case, I want Education and Awards to be right-aligned such that there is uniform spacing between Education/Awards and the content directly to the right.

Comment: Maybe see [Right alignment of column in table column - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/199744/right-alignment-of-column-in-table-column) for an example, understand what each parameter does and adapt for yourself

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to TeX.SE!

I' not sure what is your problem and how your table should looks. So I'm guessing that the following solution is what you after:

**Edit:** now consider OP comment:

[image]

MWE, which produce above result, use `tabularray` package with library `varwidth` (needed for correct work if list in table) and a bit changes list setings:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1 in]{geometry}

\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize]{nosep,
                  leftmargin=*,
                  after=\end{minipage}\vspace{-\baselineskip},                                                        before=\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth},
}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{varwidth}  % <===

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{colspec = {@{} Q[r, wd=1 in, font=\bfseries]
                            X[l] l @{}},
              rowsep = 3pt,
              measure = vbox,
            }
Education
    &   \textbf{University of Waterloo} 
        &   Waterloo, Canada    \\
    &   Bachelor of Science 
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Relevant Coursework: Computer Organization
        \end{itemize}         
        &   May 2023            \\
Awards
    &   \textbf{Google} - Google Generation Scholarship
        &   2022
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answering but I think I did a poor job explaining my question. I want Education and Awards to be right-aligned such that there is uniform spacing between Education/Awards and the content directly to the right. I tried using /flushright to right align and /hspace to create spacing but I wasn't satisfied with the size of the /hspace spacing. /hspace is supposed to allow customized spacing but whether I gave the argument of 1cm or 3cm it made no difference.

Comment: @fluttershy22, this wasnt clear. However, for this you only need to change option in the first column specification from `l` to `r`. Corrected now.